Using dot notation in Twig with attribute()
Has any one tried to do something such as {{ attribute(item, 'subItem.title') }} for accessing a structure such as in the following pseudocode:
class Item {
   private $subItem;
   
   public function __construct() { $this->subItem = new SubItem(); }
   public function getSubItem() { return $this->subItem; }
}

class SubItem {
    private $title = '';

    public function getTitle() { return $this->title; }
}

For the scenario in Twig I'm doing this, the second part of attribute is coming from a Twig variable, so I can't just do {{ item.subItem.title }}. Any thoughts on how to access the title via attribute?

It doesn't feel like the nicest solution, but I've since found the following works: {{ attribute(attribute(item, 'subItem'), 'title') }}

An example with form:
{% set dotNotation = 'subItem.title' %}
{% set field = form %}

{% for fieldName in dotNotation|split('.') %}
    {% set field = attribute(field, fieldName) %}
{% endfor %}

{{ form_row(field) }}

Or consider if the "item" object can do the same, e.g.:
{{ item.getPropertyByPath('subItem.title') }}


The attribute function will just return the variable/instance as is, meaning you can chain any method/property of the returned variable.
{{ attribute(item, property).title }}

demo
This approach will also works on arrays
{% set foo = {
    'bar': {
        'title': 'Lipsum',
    },        
} %}

{% set prop = 'bar' %}


{{ attribute(foo, prop).title }}

demo

the problem in my scenario is it's not necessarily .title in all instances (this is for a partial which different datasets of different structures could be passed into)

You haven't addressed  this in your original question though? If the title property is dynamic as well, then yes, you would need to use the attribute function again as you did in the comment posted
